# discord.js problems using args within a command

Tags: discord.js

https://gyazo.com/fc9e12129ed9bb06768cc2e02e78bf49

i just created an account to ask this question.

i've tried every possibility it feels like but whenever i type in my discord channel "!message (whatever arguement)", the bot just doesn't reply and nothing shows in console.

anything I'm doing wrong maybe?

rest of this portion of code: https://gyazo.com/0bb9ae9d599cee13d0cf68761c5cc977

Comment: Include the snippet of the code, don't post a link of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 
`message.content.startsWith === '!message'`,
Try: 
`message.content.startsWith('!message')`

Tell me if you still have any problems :)

Comment: it worked, I feel stupid for not realizing that I could use (). thank you!